# How do I save the value of seekbar which is being used to change the circle radius?

Tags: android, google-maps, seekbar

I want to save the radius of circle which user sets(i.e. value of seekbar) to generate the notification. how should I save it in SQLite database?

Comment: @Override
     public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar,int radiuss, boolean fromUser){
         circle.setRadius(radiuss);
       


     }

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in `SharedPreferences` simply

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    saveRadius(progress)
}

private void saveRadius(int radius) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("radius", radius);
    editor.apply();
}

private int getRadius() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
    return prefs.getInt("radius", 0);
}
```